# Why a dotted line in functions?

Tags: category-theory

My question is a little stupid, but I have to ask (I've never seen in anywhere an explanation) I'm studying a very short introduction of category theory by [Lee's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441979395) and I would like to ask why some authors use dotted lines like this one below, maybe because of the unicity of $f$?

[image]

Comment: The dotted line simply indicates that the corresponding map is induced by the other maps.  That is to say, given $f_{\alpha}$ and $\pi_{\alpha}$, there exists a unique $f$ so that the diagram above commutes.

Comment: @Alfred Suppose $f$ weren't unique, does it still make sense use a dotted line?

Comment: @Alfred I think the dotted line informally means a little more - "there isn't always a map which does this, but in this special situation the map exists", with the general implication "maps like this are useful, so we watch out for situations in which they exist" - with this being a strictly additional and informal addition to your comment.

Comment: In short, it's just for highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

In general, in a commutative diagram, the solid arrows are the given ones, and the dotted arrows are those which are claimed to exist. You can imagine this as a *process*:

First there is no arrow: $~X ~~~~~~~~ Y $

The arrow emerges: $~~~~~X \cdots{\small >} Y$

And finally it's there: $~~~~X \longrightarrow Y$

The unicity is not assumed. See for example the definition of a [projective module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module).

When one wants to indicate unicity, one writes for example $X \stackrel{\exists !}{\cdots {\small >}} Y$. For example, here is the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms:

[image]